# My save function is not working - I am new to Jquery

Tags: python, jquery, django

This is my first time with using jquery and I am trying to save a reply but it gives a successful message but it not actually but I can't see the reply that the system says it saved.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".reply_open_modal").click(function(){
        var id=$(this).parents("tr").children("td:eq(0)").text();
        var name=$(this).parents("tr").children("td:eq(2)").text();
        $("#reply_id").val(id);
        $("#reply_name").text(name);

    });
```

I think this part of my system works but iIam not sure and the purpose of this code is to send the reply message

```js
  $(document).on("click","#reply_btn",function(){

                $(this).attr("disabled","disabled")
                $(this).text("Sending Reply")
                
                var id=$("#reply_id").val();
                var message=$("#reply_message").val();

                $.ajax({
                        url:'{% url 'admin_message_replied' %}',
                        type:'POST',
                        data:{id:id,message:message},
                    })
                    .done(function(response){

                        if(response=="True"){
                            alert("Sent")
                        }
                        else{
                            alert("Not Sent")
                        }
                        location.reload()
                    })
                    .fail(function(){
                        alert("Error in Sending Reply")
                    })
        })
    })
```

This is the function that saves the reply into my database but it not working:

```py
@csrf_exempt 
def admin_message_replied(request):
    reply_id=request.POST.get("id")
    reply_message=request.POST.get("message")
    
    try:
        messages = SendmessageAdmin.objects.get(id=reply_id)
        messages.message_reply = reply_message
        messages.save()
        
        return HttpResponse("True")
    except:
        return HttpResponse("False")
```

Comment: On server-side, it seems like you look for `reply-message` but you sent `message`...So change `request.POST.get("reply_message")` to `request.POST.get("message")`.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette thank you for the reponse but it still not saving